# Unwanted space after lessthanequal operator: P(Z{\leq}z)

Tags: math-mode

Why is there a space after the <= sign here: `P(Z{\leq}z)`
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [Looks correct to me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zgVP.png) We're going to need more information about your document.

Answer (score 5):

If you have

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

P(Z{\leq}z)

\end{document}
```

You get an error

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.5 P(Z{\leq
            }z)
? 
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
l.5 P(Z{\leq}
             z)
?
```

[image]

Never ignore errors, TeX will recover enough to check more of the document, but not make sensible output.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$P(Z{\leq}z)$

\end{document}
```

is error free and makes

[image]

Comment: Maybe it's time to make `-halt-on-error` the default with no way to disable it, given that most editors and things like Overleaf display the PDF even though there were errors.

Comment: @HenriMenke since last week overleaf has an option to stop on first error and show the log, so gradually things get better. latex's default of course has always been to halt.

Comment: Also, `\leq` probably shouldn’t be braced if we want the correct spacing.

Comment: @Gaussler possibly, but then the question title would have been "missing space before" not "unwanted space after"

Comment: @Gaussler -- I don't understand what the expression means, but it seems that the parentheses indicate that what's inside is a condition, and not an ordinary relation where the spacing would be wider.  I would consider this equivalent to the appearance of this expression in a sub/superscript, where the spacing is compressed.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I’m pretty sure it’s a probability expression.

Comment: @Gaussler -- Yes, a probability expression has been confirmed in the chat.  I'm not familiar with that field's notation.